# Prevent user from posting duplicated data into the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, crud

I want to implement restriction on creating duplicated data in Asp.net MVC project.

I have a table tSectionForwardSelling (SectionForwardSellingID, StoreID, SectionID, Amount, Date).

I want to restrict a user to input duplicated data if data he wants to input in tSectionForwardSelling already has the same StoreID and SectionID. If data with same StoreID and SectionID exists, he can only edit.

I want to avoid this:

```
    Amount    Date       SectionName     StoreName 

    $1000   5/20/2015        Men          Clarissa 
    $2345   5/20/2015        Men          Clarissa
```

---

Here is my Create ActionResult from tSectionForwardSellings controller:

```
// GET: tSectionForwardSellings/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.SectionID = new SelectList(db.tSections, "SectionID", "Section_Name");
    ViewBag.StoreID = new SelectList(db.tStores, "StoreID", "Store_Name");
    return View();
}

// POST: tSectionForwardSellings/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "SectionForwardSellingID,Amount,Date,StoreID,SectionID")] tSectionForwardSelling tSectionForwardSelling)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.tSectionForwardSellings.Add(tSectionForwardSelling);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.SectionID = new SelectList(db.tSections, "SectionID", "Section_Name", tSectionForwardSelling.SectionID);
    ViewBag.StoreID = new SelectList(db.tStores, "StoreID", "Store_Name", tSectionForwardSelling.StoreID);
    return View(tSectionForwardSelling);
}
```

And here the project itself:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwgF9RnNTDDEOVlUMmxub2JxbFU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The approach to solve, will resolve in multiple data calls for a comparison.  Is the repetition of your command impacting performance okay?

Comment: Yes. It is a small database. Performance won't be an issue.

Comment: you should add unique constraints to the database so that it's impposible to have duplicates.

Comment: Your example doesn't include either StoreId or SectionId, what data are you really trying to avoid duplicates of? Have you considered making them primary keys, or adding a unique constraint to the columns in the database?

Comment: User can see StoreName and SectionName via ViewBag. But form posts StoreID and SectionID.

I guess i could do something like this to my database:

ALTER TABLE tSectionForwardSelling
ADD CONSTRAINT nodups UNIQUE (StoreID, SectionID)

I am a entry level developer. Still lots to learn>

Comment: I suggest you restrict user input as well.  If you don't want duplicates then you really shouldn't present your end user the ability to enter a duplicate.  After they make choice number 1 you can load a list of possible options for choice 2.  Or, load existing data when a match is found.  Of course you should still run checks.

Comment: I was thinking to put something like this right above  if (ModelState.IsValid):



if(tSectionForwardSelling.StoreID != db.tSectionForwardSellings.Find(tSectionForwardSelling.StoreID)) $$ (tSectionForwardSelling.SectionID != db.tSectionForwardSellings.Find(tSectionForwardSelling.SectionID))


But it is not a correct code

Comment: @Timur pseudo-code aside, that's also a bad idea because between when you check if it exists and when you insert it, someone else *could* come along and insert it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

Do you ever want that duplicated data to exist?

If the table should *never* contain more than 1 row for the same SectionName and StoreName values then you should solve this in the database by either creating a composite primary key (clustered index) on those 2 columns, or by creating a unique non-clustered index on those 2 columns.

Then in your .NET MVC you can also perform some checks when inserting data to check if it already exists, but you won't strictly *have* to, and your database still will never be able to get into a bad state.

Comment: How to add exception and redirect user to the same GET method (Create) if SQL constraint triggered? I added constraint to my database. When user added the same StoreID, SectionID, application crashed.

Comment: Exceptions should always be exceptional, never something you expect to encounter fairly often. So ideally you'd check first to see if a row exists, then either update or insert based on that check's result. In either case, your update/insert should be wrapped in a Try {} Catch {} block, and in the catch you can either redirect to another action, or (usually) better is to add a model error stating that there was a DB error and re-display the same view, so they can see that something went wrong

Comment: Thanks. I added constraints in MSSQL and added try catch to controller that redirects to the Error action that provides reasons for the error with link to the previous page to try again.

Answer (score 2):

I'll echo some of what's already been said and add a few thoughts.

First: have a **constraint at the database level** that prevents the duplicate scenario outright.  This is usually done with a key and some types of indexes can also force this constraint.

Second: before you add anything to the database that must be unique, **ask for a copy of the object from the database** with those parameters, if they exist, simply update the record, if they don't, add the new item.

Third: if it's a critical item that must not under any circumstance be duplicated, make sure that for the second step you **issue a lock** so that no one else can do anything with that key.   A lock will ensure that when you search for the item no one else will be able to then add it after you do.

In my own system I use a combination of SQL level locks and Cache based distributed locks.  Either way, if it's a critical component, you will want to start to understand this sort of architecture better.  In most non-critical low load scenarios you can get away with a simple look up though.